# rellax.js no puedo inicializarlo en webpack 4

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, npm, webpack

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.no-padding {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.navbar .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-light .bg-light {
    position: relative;
}
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.logo-block {
    width: 32%;
}

input[type='button'] {
    outline: none;
}

button {
    outline: none;
}

.wapper-father {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 34px);
}

.list-footer {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.lista {
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 0;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .logo-block {
        display: block;
        width: 54px;
    }
    .navbar-toggler {
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 1.25rem;
        line-height: 1;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        outline: none !important;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
        padding-left: 0;
        -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
        justify-content: space-around;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css"
            integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>O R T</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid wapper-father">
            <header>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light
                    sticky-top">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img src="img/logotipo.jpg"
                            class="logo-block align-top" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
                        data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText"
                        aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home
                                    <span
                                        class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <main>
                <section>
                    <div class="rellax">
                        Iâ€™m that default chill speed of "-2"
                    </div>
                    <div class="rellax" data-rellax-speed="7">
                        Iâ€™m super fast!!
                    </div>
                    <div class="rellax" data-rellax-speed="-4">
                        Iâ€™m extra slow and smooth
                    </div>
                </section>
            </main>
        </div>
        <footer class="footer">
            <ul class="list-footer">
                <li class="lista">Â© O R T
                </li>
                <li class="lista"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        js: "./src/index.js"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js"
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "html-loader?minimize=true"

                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    // "css-loader?minimize&sourceMap",
                    "css-loader",
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            autoprefixer: {
                                browser: ["last 2 versions"]
                            },

                            sourceMap: true,
                            minimize: true,
                            plugins: () => [autoprefixer]
                        }
                    },
                    "resolve-url-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|webp)$/i,
                use: [
                    "file-loader?name=assets/img/[name].[ext]",
                    "image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff2?|mp4|mp3|txt|xml|pdf)$/i,
                use: "file-loader?name=assets/[name].[ext]"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(["dist/**/*.*"]),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].[chunkhash].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./src/template.html",
            filename: "index.html",
            chunks: ["js"]
        })
    ]
};
```

```js
import bootstrap from "bootstrap"
import styles from "./scss/app.scss";
import rellaxCss from "../src/css/rellax.css";
import style from "../src/css/styles.css";
import rellax from "../src/js/rellax.js"


export default {
    init() {
      var rellax = new Rellax('.rellax');
      rellax;
    },
    finalize() {
     
    },
  };
```

```html
<div class="rellax">
  I’m that default chill speed of "-2"
</div>
<div class="rellax" data-rellax-speed="7">
  I’m super fast!!
</div>
<div class="rellax" data-rellax-speed="-4">
  I’m extra slow and smooth
</div>
```

Comment: Instale desde npm con webpack 4 la librería pero cuando la compilo con webpack me aparece en la consola indefined